# Grep all text following a specific format

Tags: php, regex, grep, preg-replace

Hi ALl i have a list that look something like so

```
curl -x X3SzDf34
curl -x X3SzDf34r
curl -a X3SzDf43
curl -x X3SzDfsdf
curl -a X3SzDfsvx
```

basically looking to grep all lines that have curl -X and to select the entire line. The IDE i use has the grep search functionality built in so im trying to use that to delete the lines that have the curl -x. Keep in mind its a list of about 1000 lines. Can anyone please help.

I tried the following

```
 curl -x ([a-z, A-Z, 0-9])
```

but that didnt work. Any help would be appreciated. How do i search for a specific text in the front followed by any other combination of letters number and maybe even symbols.

Comment: read the lines in to an array loop it, if the  the first 7 characters are "curl -x" ignore, keep the rest.

Comment: i suppose that will work but i figured since i can use the grep functionality in my IDE i can just do search and replace with a space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are talking about [preg_grep](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-grep.php) function, and I would suggest you to use this pattern:

```
(curl -x\s*.+)
```

along with `PREG_GREP_INVERT` flag so it will return all the lines that do not have `curl -x bla blah`.

Hope it helps.